# Installing Service from the appx bundle created from MSI using Desktop Application converter

Tags: service, uwp, appx, dac, desktop-bridge

I want to package a windows service as an appx bundle. I used below link to create MSI for installing service.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/816169/how-to-create-a-setup-project-for-a-windows-service-application-in-visual-c

MSI working fine, service installed successfully. Now when I had used this MSI for creating APPX by using DAC converter, i found appx was created but when launch it, I am getting dialog box indicating "cannot start service from the command line or debugger,A windows service must first be installed...". But in MSI is working fine.

Thus I am eager to know that whether DAC converter supports installation of service if MSI can installs service perfectly and if not then how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

Installing a Windows service with an .appx package is not supported as this work break the model and the guarantees around isolation.

See the third bullet in the preparation guide for Desktop Bridge packaging/conversion:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare

Depending on what you are using the service for, you maybe able to replace it with a long-running background process or a UWP background task. If you are using the service to facilitate auto-updates, you will no longer it as the converted app will be receiving updates from the Store automatically.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform